Is there any straight line lying on $z=x-(y(1-x))/(1-y)$.
I have a surface defined by $z=f(x,y):=x-\frac{y(1-x)}{1-y}$ for $x,y\in (0,1)$. And I would like to know if there exists any straight line lying on the surface and here is what I have tried: Parametrise the straight line by $z(t)=z_0+z_1t, x(t)=x_0+x_1t, y(t)=y_0+y_1t, t\in [0,1]$ where the $x_i,y_i,z_i$ are coefficient to be determined. Substitute these into the surface we get $z(t)=x(t)-\frac{y(t)(1-x(t))}{1-y(t)}$. Letting $t\rightarrow 0$, we have $z_0=x_0-\frac{y_0(1-x_0)}{1-y_0}$. But then I don't know what else I can do to proceed.

Think $y\neq1, w=1.$ There are two rulings on the quadric surface $$-yz-xw+yw+zw=0,$$ meaning there are two families of lines, all skew within the ruling. All meet exactly one line of the other, where the plane they make is tangent. It is given by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&-\frac12\0&0&-\frac12&\frac12\0&-\frac12&0&\frac12\-\frac12&\frac12&\frac12&0\end{pmatrix}$$ which is full rank of signature $++--,$ making the lines real. In the plane at infinity $w=0$ we get $yz=0,$ meaning that the plane at infinity is tangent to the quadric surface. This should make it a hyperbolic paraboloid

You can take the line with parametric equation $z=0, x=y=t$, since
$$
f(t,t) = t - \frac{t(1-t)}{1-t} = 0,
$$
as long as $t \in (0,1)$.
To come to this solution I tried to see for which values of $x$ and $y$ the function $f$ becomes linear. I then noticed that the fraction disappears if we set $x=y$.

$x+yz-y-z=0,y\neq1$
the vector must be $(a,0,c)$
$x=a,y=0,z=a$ is a straight line.

Hi, thanks for your help but $x,y \in (0,1)$ so $y$ can't be $0$.
